# How can I change the OCI Runtime in Podman

Tags: podman

I know that in Docker if you want to change the runtime you go to: /etc/docker/daemon.json

And modify:

```
{
    "runtimes": {
        "runnc": {
            "path": "/usr/sbin/runnc"
        }
    }
}
```

But how do I do this with Podman (or just add runtime)?

> OCIRuntime: package:
>
> runc: /usr/sbin/runc
>
> path: /usr/sbin/runc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the `runtime_path` defaults in `/usr/share/containers/libpod.conf` and overwrite them in `/etc/containers/libpod.conf` (on EL8, check `man podman` to find correct place for Your setup).
As there is no daemon this is the conifguration used for all the libpod commands that need to know that.

---

Edit: as stated by @jnbdz the probably more important default location: in rootless mode `$HOME/.config/containers/libpod.conf`

Comment: I found mine here : ~/.config/containers/libpod.conf

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot. That one is also a default, for users settings.

Comment: I think this answer is old. Can't find the file libpod.conf in any of the locations mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

Container engines will read containers.conf files in up to three
locations in the following order:

1. `/usr/share/containers/containers.conf`
2. `/etc/containers/containers.conf`
3. `$HOME/.config/containers/containers.conf` (Rootless containers ONLY)

Items specified in the latter containers.conf, if they exist, override the
previous containers.conf settings, or the default settings.

Found this written at top of the `/usr/share/containers/containers.conf`

Comment: This is the right answer. You have to set the option under the `[engine]` table: `runtime ="crun"`

Answer (score 1):

I found this config as: /usr/share/containers/containers.conf
OS: rocky 8
podman: 4.2.0

And I set the default runtime as crun.

Comment: Your modifications of the file  _/usr/share/containers/containers.conf_ might be overwritten when RPMs are updated. I think the file to  edit is  _/etc/containers/containers.conf_